# Network timeouts

Tags: networking, dhcp

I have an "auto" DHCP interface, with my default DHCP timeout (in dhclient.conf) set to 300 seconds.

I turn off the DHCP server.

When the computer boots up, it times out for ~300 seconds (~5 minutes).  When it comes up, there are no sub-interfaces available!  eth0:1 doesn't come up, but all the eth0s come up, including the DHCP interface with no IP address.

I then set the timeout to 15 seconds and power-cycle the computer.

This time it appears to timeout for ~15 seconds, but when the system fully comes up, all the sub-interface ARE available!  eth0:1, as well as all the eth0s, including the DHCP interface with no IP address.

What gives?  This seems strange...the timeout is being hit in both cases, so why does it behave differently?

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh a friend figured this out!

/etc/systemd/system/network-online.targets.wants/networking.service has a 5 minute timeout, the same time as the DHCP timeout.  So the service dies before it brings up the rest of the interface, wasting most of it's 5 minutes waiting on DHCP.

Close this bad boy down!